# Converting data from multiple Hive Tables to Complex JSON

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I have data across two hive tables that I need to join and generate a JSON Object. I found few libraries (BrickHouse, OpenX) to have hive table map to a complex JSON schema. However, I am not able to find a way to get the results from the two tables into this Hive table.

E.g:

> Table-A
>
> Col1          Col2
>
> "userLogins"     30
>
> Table B
>
> Col1           Col2            Col3
>
> "userLogins"    "Site A"        10
>
> "userLogins"    "Site B"        20
>
> I want to generate a JSON Object such as :
>
> {   name: "userLogins",
>
> children: [{name: "Site A", logins:10}, {name: "Site B", logins:20}]
>   }

I have tried finding any clues to a possible solution but most links online are about converting JSON to Hive Table and not vice versa. Is there a better/easier way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using the `to_json` UDF from [Brickhouse](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/json/ToJsonUDF.java). Once you build the jar file, you can add the jar and create a temporary function as:

```
add jar /path/brickhouse-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION to_json AS 'brickhouse.udf.json.ToJsonUDF';
```

I tested the UDF with the sample data you had given.

```
describe table_a;
col_1                   string                  None                
col_2                   int                     None                

describe table_b; 
col_1                   string                  None                
col_2                   string                  None                
col_3                   int                     None                

select * from table_a;
userLogins  30

select * from table_b;
userLogins  Site A  10
userLogins  Site B  20

select
to_json(named_struct( 'name', a.col_1, 'children' , array(named_struct('name', b.col_2, 'logins', b.col_3))))
from table_a a
join table_b b
on a.col_1 = b.col_1;

{"name":"userLogins","children":[{"name":"Site B","logins":20}]}
{"name":"userLogins","children":[{"name":"Site A","logins":10}]}
```

You can find more details about the usage of the UDF from [Brickhouse blog](http://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/hive-and-json-made-simple/).

Comment: Is it possible to use to_json without knowing the column names? I want to include all column names in JSON and each table can have different column names.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the the collect UDF from brickhouse.

```
select named_struct(
    'name', b.col_1, 
    'children',  collect(named_struct('name', b.col_2, 'logins', b.col_3))) 
from table_a a join table_b b
on a.col_1 = b.col_1
group by b.col_1;
```

The above outputs the below json

```
{"name":"userLogins","children":[{"name":"Site A","logins":10},{"name":"Site B","logins":20}]}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use to_json without knowing the column names? I want to include all column names in JSON and each table can have different column names